# How do stateful bidirectional RNNs work in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, bidirectional

In Keras the `Bidirectional` wrapper for RNNs also supports `stateful=true`. I don't really understand how this is supposed to work:

In a stateful unidirectional model the state of a batch is carried over to the next batch. I guess it works the same for the forward layer in the bidirectional model.

But where is the backward layer getting it's states from? If I understand everything correctly it should technically recieve it's state from the "next" batch. But obviously the "next" batch is not computet yet, so how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

One may think about a `Bidirectional` layer in a following manner:

```
forward = Recurrent(..)(input)
backward = Recurrent(..., reverse_input=True)(input)
output = merge([forward, backward], ...)
```

So - as you can see - you are losing the *temporal* orientation. You are analysing the input both from its beginning and end. In this case - setting `stateful=True` simply takes its starting state from a previous sample accordingly to direction of a bidirectional branch (`forward` takes from `forward`, `backward` takes from `backward`).

This makes your model losing the interpretation - that samples from concurrent batches might be interpreted as a compact sequence divided into batches.